# Using Glide Library: How to set camera icon on the right side of a profile image?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-glide

I'm using Glide library to get user's profile image from url and display it in ImageView view.
I want to set camera icon on the right side of that profile image exactly like below.

[image]

Here is my imave view:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="700dp" />
```

Glide:

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Glide.with(imageView) 
                .load(URL) 
                .circleCrop() 
                .placeholder(setCircularImage(R.drawable.prof)) 
                .error(setCircularImage(R.drawable.t)) 
                .fallback(setCircularImage(R.drawable.camera_red))
                .into(imageView);
```

How could I do that, Whic library should I use to make camera icon on the right side of a profile image ?

I don't want the icon overlap the profile image. I want the profile image to be cropped to give place to camera icon(Like on facebook app profile image). Thanks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to do with Glide. You can use ConstraintLayout, FrameLayout or RelativeLayout to overlap ImageViews.

Comment: I don't want the icon overlap the profile image. I want the profile image to be cropped to give place to camera icon. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid that cannot be done easily. You have create a custom view for that. Overlapping is the best option here.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Relative layout to achieve this like below

```html
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:layout_marginTop="700dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/imageView"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:bott="true"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_vector_test"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and then adjust it accordingly.
Happy coding :)

Comment: I don't want the icon overlap the profile image. I want the profile image to be cropped to give place to camera icon. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first you should use `circleImageView` in your layout and then set two of them like this:

```
<CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/circleImg1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>

<CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/circleImg2"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/circleImg1"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/circleImg1"
    android:layout_height="15dp"/>
```